# Some methods in another thread cannot be executed in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

#### Problem

After clicking logout button, some actions sometimes are not executed. In the code below, sometimes the `hideTabBar()` and `showAuth()` seem not to be executed, but sometimes they are executed. Why?

#### Source Code

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public void selectLogout(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Logout").setMessage("Are you sure you wanna logout?");
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mWebview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mWebview.loadUrl(WEB_BASE + LOGOUT_TAG);
                    btnSlide.performClick();
                    hideTabBar();
                    showAuth();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    mAlertDialogBuilder.show();
}
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

The `android:onClick="selectLogout"` is used to bind the `onClick` callback function to the logout button.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/button_state_resource"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="selectLogout" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_logout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:text="Logout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **Never** executed? Are your sure? How much did you wait? Put a breakpoint there and see if it stops.

Comment: maybe you need to call `refresh/repaint` or something implicitly!

Comment: Is your application exiting after logout? Maybe the execution is terminated, before the WebView handler has a chance to execute the delayed runnable. The short delay of half a second may explain why this seems to occur randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, any UI related changes MUST happen on the UI thread. Thus, if you try to change the UI in a background thread, it might throw errors. To solve this, you can use a `Handler` that can post jobs to the UI thread to run in sequence.

example:

```
private Handler handler;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //....some stuff
    //initialize Handler
    handler = new Handler();
}


public void selectLogout(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Logout").setMessage("Are you sure you wanna logout?");
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mWebview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // update UI
                            mWebview.loadUrl(WEB_BASE + LOGOUT_TAG);
                            btnSlide.performClick();
                            hideTabBar();
                            showAuth();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    mAlertDialogBuilder.show();
}
```